# Why web applications do not allow to change username

Tags: php, security, authentication

I am developing a web application which contains a user login. In the web I have seen that many web applications do not allow users to change the username once the account is registered. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Duplicate: [Why should usernames be unchangable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216380/why-should-usernames-be-unchangable)

Comment: I have recently came across this dilemma whether to allow user to change username. I have entered it on my blog:
http://www.dizkover.com/post/423/programming-why-not-to-allow-users-to-change-username-in-social-web-application-design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's more personal preference to be able to keep track of who posts what rather than any real security concern. I see no security issue in allowing a user to change their username, but you will have users that try to imitate other usernames and admin usernames to confuse and possibly socially engineer information.